# Custom View disappears when aligned within a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-relativelayout

I have a custom view that simply draws a circle onto a canvas (so far). 
Using it within a RelativeLayout is fine until I tell it specifically where to be aligned within the RelativeLayout.

i.e. as soon as I add something like: android:layout_centerInParent="true"
it will no longer appear.

The following is the relevant code:

```
public class CircleProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

int radius;
float centerX;
float centerY;

Paint progressPaint;

public CircleProgressBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CircleProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CircleProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    progressPaint = new Paint();
    progressPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    progressPaint = new Paint();
    progressPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    radius = Math.max(getMeasuredWidth(), getWidth()) / 2;
    centerX = getLeft() + radius;
    centerY = getTop() + radius;

    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, progressPaint);
}
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.tomtaila.circleprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you check values in onDraw() method? What the data do you transfer into the drawCircle()?

Comment: What does your onMeasure implementation look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. This will fix your problem

Remove "android:layout_centerInParent="true"" from "CircleProgressBar" and 
set "android:gravity="center"" to the "activity_main" RelativeLayout

OR

```
@Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        radius = Math.max(getMeasuredWidth(), getWidth()) / 2;
        centerX = radius;
        centerY = radius;

        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, progressPaint);
    }
```

While CircleProgressBar tag without centerInParent attribute, Its position is Top left (0,0). So in "onDraw" method you are using getLeft() return 0 and getTop() return 0.

But While CircleProgressBar tag with centerInParent attribute, Its position is center of the parent (parent_width/2,parent_height/2). So In "onDraw" method  getLeft() will return parent_width/2() (if parent width is 480, then it will return 240)  and simmilarlly getTop() will return parent_height/2. Now centerX, centerY values become too big.

Comment: @tomtaila Updated my post. Please check it